# display one question on radio button change and submit the user answer after every 3 questions react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux

I am new to React, I have a set of random 120 questions from which every time 3 questions are shown to user, and when all 3 questions are filled user submit and then next set of 3 questions loads. I want to show 1 question out of 3 and on every radio button checked show next question and when the 3 questions are answered submit button shows next set of question.

```
const Quiz = () => {
    const {questions, quiz, options} = useSelector((state) => state.quiz);
    
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const history = useHistory();
    const classes = useStyles();
    
   
// this is to get thel questions from the history coming from redux store.
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!questions) {
            dispatch(fetcQuestions(history));
          
        }

    }, []);

      const handleRadioChange = (number, event) => {
        let currentSelection = questions.find(question => question.number === number);
        console.log(currentSelection + "radio selected");
        currentSelection.value = event.target.value;
        console.log(currentSelection.value + "calculate score");
    };

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        }
    };
    return (
        
        !questions?.length ? <CircularProgress /> : (
                     <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

                    {questions.map((question) => (
                        <FormControl component="fieldset" key={question.number} className={classes.formControl}>
                            <FormLabel component="legend">{question.question}</FormLabel>
                            <RadioGroup aria-label="quiz" name="quiz" value={question.value} onChange={(e) => handleRadioChange(question.number, e)}>
                                {options.map((option) => 
                                    <FormControlLabel key={option.number} value={option.number} control={<Radio />} label={option.label} />
                                    
                               )}
                            </RadioGroup>
                        </FormControl>
                        

                    ))}

                    <Button type="submit" variant="outlined" color="primary" className={classes.button}>
                        Submit
                </Button>
              
                </form>
           
        )
    );
};
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank You.

---

I have attempted this by adding 2 states but the problem is I am not able to match the question number with the curent ques no

```
const Quiz = () => {
    const {questions, quiz, options} = useSelector((state) => state.quiz);
    
    const [current_question, setCurrentQuestion] = useState();
    console.log(current_question[number] + "1q");
    
   
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const history = useHistory();
    const location = useLocation();
    const classes = useStyles();
    

// this is to get thel questions from the history coming from redux store.
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!questions) {
            dispatch(fetcQuestions(history));
          
         
        }

    }, []);

      const handleRadioChange = (number, event) => {
        let currentSelection = questions.find(question => question.number === number);
        console.log(currentSelection + "radio selected");
        currentSelection.value = event.target.value;
        console.log(currentSelection.value + "calculate score");
        let new_current_questions = Math.min(
            current_question + 1,
            questions.length - 1
          );
          console.log(new_current_questions);
        setCurrentQuestion(new_current_questions);
    };

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        
    };
    return (
        
        !questions?.length ? <CircularProgress /> : (
            <Grid className={classes.container} container alignItems="stretch" spacing={1}>
             
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                   
                    {questions.map((question) => (
                        
                        <FormControl component="fieldset" key={question.number} className={classes.formControl} data-hidden={question.number !== current_question[question.number]}>
                            <FormLabel component="legend">{question.question}</FormLabel>
                            <RadioGroup aria-label="quiz" name="quiz" value={question.value} onChange={(e) => handleRadioChange(question.number, e)}>
                                {options.map((option) => 
                                    <FormControlLabel key={option.score} value={option.score} control={<Radio />} label={option.label} />
                                    
                               )}
                            </RadioGroup>
                        </FormControl>
                        

                    ))}

                    <Button type="submit" variant="outlined" color="primary" className={classes.button}>
                        Submit
                </Button>
              
                </form>
            </Grid>
        )
    );
};



export default Quiz;
```

I added data-hidden field to display none; so that current question is only shown but all 3 questions are coming. I think the problem is that i am not getting the array of ques num. Please help

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am getting 3 questions at one time. Not getting one question and next question on radio button clicked. please help @Tom

Comment: You need to give more of your code. What does `fetchQuestions` do? Also, you shouldn't use a radio button on its own. You probably want a checkbox instead

Comment: fetchQuestions get the questions from the database which is stored in redux store.
any specific reason for not using radio button? I want only one option to be selected?

Comment: @Tom i think the functionality is to be added in the part questions.map but i am unable to get that done.

Comment: Your DOM structure means that each radio button is in a separate group, so a user can select all of them if they want.
As for `fetchQuestions`, I think it's likely that function is giving you 3 questions at once

Comment: @Tom i need 3 questions at once, but i need to show 1 question at a time, so you mean I need to change the code in fetchQuestion. But i need 3 questions at one time and want to display those questions 1/3 and on radio select 2/3 and on 3/3 submit button.

Comment: @Tom i think handleRadioChange function is the place where the next question will be shown. may be state is to be set.? i am bit confused, if you can help me out

Comment: You will need a separate state variable that handles how many questions you want to reveal, which you can update in `handleRadioChange` and then filter your question array by the index.

Comment: @Tom can you please make a pseudo code, so that it will be clear to me as I am newbie and its a crucial part. I will be highly grateful to you for the help. Please put the pseudo code so it will be easier to me to understand.

Comment: @Tom The questions are coming in random order, then how to filter array on the basis of index. Please provide the pseudo code, asap. i have to complete it by today. I am in dire need to get it done and i am stuck here. Thank You.

Comment: @Tom can you please give a pseudo code for this problem.

Comment: @Jacob Smit please help, i am a newbie can you provide the pseudo code for my problem.

Comment: @ouflak please help in this code.

Comment: @Muqito please help in this question. Thanks

Comment: I think you misunderstand the way this site is designed to function. Unfortunately it isn't somewhere that you post your code and ask for someone else to do work on it for you. According to the guidelines, you should describe attempts to solve the problem, which you haven't shown any evidence of

Comment: @Tom i have edited the question with the attempt i have made.

Comment: @Tom please check I have added the attempt i have made. I think the array of 3 questions i am not getting therefore I am unable to match ques with current ques

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your attempt you don't set an initial value for your `current_question` state, so when you go to increment it, you're doing the operation:
`undefined + 1`.

You also need to conditionally render the questions, either by filtering them beforehand or when you map them to JSX:

```
const Quiz = () => {
    const { questions, quiz, options } = useSelector((state) => state.quiz);
    
    const [currentQuestion, setCurrentQuestion] = useState(0);
    console.log(currentQuestion[number] + "1q");
    
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const history = useHistory();
    const location = useLocation();
    const classes = useStyles();
    

    // this is to get the questions from the history coming from redux store.
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!questions) {
            dispatch(fetchQuestions(history));
        }
    }, []);

      const handleRadioChange = (number, event) => {
        let currentSelection = questions.find(question => question.number === number);
        console.log(currentSelection + "radio selected");
        currentSelection.value = event.target.value;
        console.log(currentSelection.value + "calculate score");
        // Set the new question count based on the current one
        setCurrentQuestion((current) => {
          return Math.min(
            current + 1,
            questions.length - 1
          );
        });
    };

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
    };
    return (
        !questions?.length ? <CircularProgress /> : (
            <Grid className={classes.container} container alignItems="stretch" spacing={1}>
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    {/* Only show the question if it's index is less than or equal to the current question */}
                    {questions.map((question, index) => (index <= currentQuestion ? (
                        <FormControl component="fieldset" key={question.number} className={classes.formControl} data-hidden={question.number !== current_question[question.number]}>
                            <FormLabel component="legend">{question.question}</FormLabel>
                            <RadioGroup aria-label="quiz" name="quiz" value={question.value} onChange={(e) => handleRadioChange(question.number, e)}>
                                {options.map((option) => 
                                    <FormControlLabel key={option.score} value={option.score} control={<Radio />} label={option.label} />
                               )}
                            </RadioGroup>
                        </FormControl>
                    ) : null))}
                    <Button type="submit" variant="outlined" color="primary" className={classes.button}>
                        Submit
                </Button>
                </form>
            </Grid>
        )
    );
};

export default Quiz;
```

Comment: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  is showing for  {questions.map((question, index) => {index <= currentQuestion ? (

I think its showing for {index<=currentQuestion. Please rectify this.
@Tom

Comment: in your answer, I changed  <FormControl component="fieldset" key={question.number} className={classes.formControl} data-hidden={question.number !== current_question}> But still all 3 questions are coming on page load instead of 1 question at a time. and data-hidden is setting true but not displaying none. please look. 
3 random questions are coming, i have to show 1 question on page load and then when radio button selected next question comes.

Comment: just added  {questions.map((question, index) => {return index <= currentQuestion ? (
Thank You.
else error was coming. @Tom.

Comment: i have added setCurrentQuestion((current) => {
          return Math.min(
            current + 1,
            questions.length - 1
          );
        });
on handleSubmit to get the same functionality as it is happening on handleRadioChange but its not working. Can you please check?